# Getting unauthorized 401 in angularjs on localhost:3000 for backend

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I have a angularjs front end running on port `8080` with the backend on port `3000`.
The backend currently works fine using POSTMAN.

But when I combine them I get the following

[image]

My setup for the backend is:

```
//Global CORS configuration
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*");
        }
    };
}
```

The security setup is (no login page , but HTTP basic):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
      .and()
      .httpBasic()
      .and()
      .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

}

@Bean
public CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint getBasicAuthEntryPoint(){
    return new CustomBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
}
```

Front end Angular:

```
app.factory('SurveysService', function($q, $http) {

var encodedUserNameAndPassword = btoa('admin:letme1');
// $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + 
// Base64.encode($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);

 $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encodedUserNameAndPassword;
var ss = 'http://localhost:3000';
return {
    getSurveys : function() {
        return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            $http.get(ss+'/surveys?start=1&limit=10').then(function(response) {
                resolve(response.data)
            },
            function(response){
                reject(response)
            })
        })

    }}

})
```

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: 401 is not a CORS issue

Comment: It's Authorization Issue, please once again look into spring security. 
Please try again with passing `header` to `ADMIN` instead of `admin`.

Comment: @user3145373 my user 'admin' is a in memory user who has Role 'ADMIN'. I have looked into spring security can't work it out. What do you mean look at header?

Comment: `$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']` ?? Shouldn't it be `$http.defaults.headers['Authorization']`

Comment: no luck @lealceidiro. Same issue.

Comment: Guys, guys i have been so so stupid. its working. The issue is I was supplying the wrong credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Error on my part. My angular client was supplying incorrect credentials. Once I corrected these it was all good.Thanks to all that tried to help.